# Would writing my own ecommerce site result in my site most likely getting hacked?

Tags: php, security, paypal

I am considering redoing my WordPress website by rewriting myself to get something a little lighter weight. The only problem I see myself getting into is rewriting my WooCommerce section. I certainly don't want anyone getting in danger. I will only be using Paypal but we still have to collect shipping information.

Comment: If you have a budget for code review and pen testing then go for it

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Afaik such services are a little bit over-priced and over-estimated in the daily practice, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it too much of a security risk to write my own online store?

Simple answer: Unless you are an expert, it is generally too risky to write your own anything. Well, you *can* write stuff, just [don't use it or publish it for others to use](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it) unless you're damn sure it's secure. Since you're asking, I'm going to assume you're not an expert.

> The only problem I see myself getting into is rewriting my WooCommerce section. I certainly don't want anyone getting in danger. I will only be using Paypal but we still have to collect shipping information. Any thoughts?

I can't speak to the security features of WooCommerce, as I've never audited a WooCommerce project as of this writing.

Unless you can do it better than what's available, use what's available. They might have prevented vulnerabilities that you would never even have thought could exist.

However, if you're doing it for your own educational purposes, please *do* experiment with your own solutions. You might find a better way to implement a feature than what already exists and possibly not realize it.

As long as you make it plain and clear that the code is experimental, and you don't actually deploy it to a production system without getting examined by a security expert, the "don't write your own" advice can be ignored.

Comment: What would be the best way to get code tested for educational purposes?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and http://security.stackexchange.com/